# Discord-py - Using Guild ID as the Guild Object

Tags: python-requests, discord, discord.py

I have been trying to print in the console all channels IDs of a server with just the guild's ID; I've been reading the docs to make it:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Guild, and this is what I've done so far.

```
@client.command()
async def getchannels(ctx, id):
    a = client.get_guild(id)
    for c in a.channels():
        print(c.id)
```

But once I run the command, I get this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channels'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation for  [`client.get_guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_guild#discord.Client.get_guild), it states that it will return `None` if the guild could not be found which is what is happening here and is what is causing your error. Because `None` is being returned and you are trying to access `channels` on what is being returned, it is throwing an error because `None` doesn't have an attribute called `channels`.

The reason why `get_guild` can return `None` is because it only checks its internal cache for a guild and doesn't actually make an API call. So if the guild is not in the cache, it will return `None`. The solution is to use [`client.fetch_guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=fetch_guild#discord.Client.fetch_guild) instead. The difference between `get_guild` and `fetch_guild` is that `fetch_guild` will send a request to the API instead of looking in the internal cache. Another thing to keep in mind is that you may not have access to a guild, in which case a [`Forbidden`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=fetch_guild#discord.Forbidden) exception will be raised. Another issues is that you are doing `guild.channels()` when you should be doing `guild.channels`. The channels attribute isn't a function so you don't need to call it with the two parenthesis.
Finally, `fetch_guild` is an async function which means you need to `await` it.

Here is some example code:

```py
from discord import Forbidden

@client.command()
async def get_channels(ctx, id):
    try:
        guild = await client.get_guild(id)
    except Forbidden:
        await ctx.send("I do not have access to that guild or it doesn't exist.")
    else:
        for channel in guild.channels:
            print(channel.id)
```