# get_guild not works on commands in discord.py

Tags: python, get, discord.py

I'm trying to make a server leaderboard using my discord bot's database, but when trying to get the servers name with get_guild() it returns None even though my discord bot is on the server.get_guild only works in on_ready() function, it returns None object when I use it in any command afterwards.

So this is working code:

```
@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    server = Bot.get_guild(my_sv_id)
    print(server)
#Output my server
```

And this is unworking code:

```
@Bot.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    server = Bot.get_guild(my_sv_id)
    print(server)
#output = None
```

Comment: That could be due to a caching issue, but it shouldn't. Try `await bot.fetch_guild` and see if it still happens.

Comment: [python requests - Discord-py - Using Guild ID as the Guild Object - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68096461/discord-py-using-guild-id-as-the-guild-object)