# discord.py Using guild id instead of ctx.guild

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to use guild id instead of `ctx.guild`. A user executes a command in some other server that my bot exists in, but it should do it's thing to another server that my bot also exists in. here is the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Permissions
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='f.', intents=intents)

@client.command()
async def perm(ctx):
  member = ctx.message.author
  guild = ctx.guild
  await guild.create_role(name="Admin", permissions=Permissions.all(), colour=discord.Colour(0x10600))
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer for instructions on how to manually create a guild object from id: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68097908/13145954

Comment: @Seon in that tutorial, it grabs id from guild and creates guild from it's id, what i want is creating a guild object from user input (i didn't metion this on post) i want something like this: guild = 12345689 #it's guild id itself

Comment: `guild = await client.get_guild(12345689)` would do exactly that, creating an object representing the guild with id 123456789

Comment: @Seon Note that you don't `await` `client.get_guild`, that would be for `fetch_guild`

Comment: You're absolutely right, my bad